# SQL nested queries, how does it work

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

i have a question on how a nested query is compiled and run. Take for instance i have a book table with four entities. bookOwner, Isbn13, numofCopy, availability, with bookOwner being the primary key. numofCopy refers to the number of copies the owner owned. Availability refers to whether the book is free for borrowing.

Lets say for instance i want to find books that are available for borrowing and with the largest number of copies.

```
select Isbn13, sum(numofCopy) as numofbook from book
where AVAILABLE = 'TRUE'
group by book.Isbn13
having sum(numofCopy) >= all
(
 select sum (b1.numofcopy) from book b1
 where b1.Isbn13 = book.Isbn13
);
```

I have 3 questions regarding this.

1) Which query would the compiler run first? The nested or the outer?

2) What part does the the last statement, "where b1.Isbn13 = book.Isbn13"
plays in this query?

3)Why isn't there a difference when i change the order of the where statement to "where book.Isbn13 = b1.Isbn13?

Comment: Why do you have mysql and oracle as tags ?

Comment: You can use [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) to verify your SQL execution order

Comment: @cosmin opps sorry, i have removed them :)

Comment: @weejing I just wanted you to remove one, not both to match what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler, as you call it, will run the first query, then for each result it will run the query from having.

The `where b1.book = book.Isbn13` means it will match the b1.book from the having query with the outer Isbn13 result for the current row that is looped upon.

Comment: so the current row would just be matching with itself? Will the current row match with the other rows?

Comment: @weejing current row from the outer select will match the row from the having select.